# Mstests only working on Debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mstest

I´ve some MSTests that currently are only working when I debug them, but not when I try to simple run.

What happens is that the code throws a runtime exception due to an "outdated" dll reference;

Let´s say my test project depends upon project foo.dll

foo.dll has a Enum which accepts 4 values already (A,B,C,D)

When I run tests on debug mode, it works fine. But on "run mode", the runtimeexception says that value (D) is not allowed, as if it was referring to an old copy of that dll (where D was not yet implemented)

I tried cleaning the solution but I suppose there is some wrong configuration on my VisualStudio setup.

No matter what I do on that enum (i.e adding a fith option), it always picks the old version.

Since I´m not able to debug (otherwise it simply works), I´m having a hard time figuring it out.

I noticed that after I migrated towards VS2015 btw.

Comment: Use Fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot assembly resolution problems.  Log all binds.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t know exactly why, but fixed it replacing .testsettings with .runsettings while I was investigating another issue:

[MStests taking too long to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562071/mstests-taking-too-long-to-load)